# Angular service functions can't be accessed in Jasmine Tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm fairly new to Jasmine Testing and the Angular framework. I currently have a peculiar situation where I'm unable to reference my service functions from my Jasmine tests.

Part of my Angular Service Initialization:

```
var service = {
checkIfCurrentIsObject: checkIfCurrentIsObject,
removeFromCurrentObject: removeFromCurrentObject;
}

function checkIfCurrentIsObject() {
          return getCurrent().isObject();
       }

function removeFromCurrentIsObject() {
         checkIfCurrentIsObject();
          return specialFunction();
       }
```

Now in my Karma Test:

```
describe('when current object is property', function() {

             it('verify the requote function is called', function() {
             spyOn(Service, 'checkIfCurrentIsObject').and.returnValue(true);
             spyOn(Service, 'removeFromCurrentIsObject').and.callThrough();
             spyOn(Service, 'specialFunction');
             expect(Service, 'specialFunction').toHaveBeenCalled();

                    });
```

Now the issue I'm facing is, my spyOn does not pick up on my checkIfCurrentIsObject function UNLESS I specify it as `this.checkIfCurrentIsObject` in my `removeFromCurrentIsObject` function. Is there a particular reason to thiss?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be

```
 function removeFromCurrentIsObject() {
     this.checkIfCurrentIsObject();
     return this.specialFunction();
 }
```

to spy on them.

It is `Service.checkIfCurrentIsObject` method that is being spied on. In JavaScript there's no way how `checkIfCurrentIsObject()` local function call could be traced.